# EGit class keeps going out of index

Tags: git, egit

I have just added a project to a local EGit repo. I created a .gitignore and put a copy in the root of the git folder and in the root of the projects folder in the git folder.

```
# ignore all __pycache__ directories
# matches "__pycache__" in any subfolder
__pycache__/

# ignore all files ending with .pyc
*.pyc
```

Then on the project I selected RMB-> Team->Share.
All files in the project appeared in the Staged Changes pane (including .pyc files I specified to ignore). I then manually selected 'ignore' then 'remove from git index' for each of the .pyc files.

Not sure if I have done something wrong via this process as now when I make any changes to a class, the class, package and project have a '>' in front of them in the package explorer and the class appears in the Unstaged Changes pane only. To commit it I then need to RMB on the class->add to git index then it appears in the Stages Changes pane.

For previous projects on changing a class, a black star would appear next to the class and it would appear in the Staged Changes pane and I did not need to re-add the class back to the git index on every commit. Is this fixable?

Comment: Seems to have fixed itself somewhat. Now when I modify a class, in most packages a * appears and on commit of the root package, the class appears with a ticked status in the commit changed dialog. However on some packages a > appears, and for classes in these, while they appear in the commit changes to repo dialog, they are unticked. These show their status as 'Untracked'. Is there a way to force everything to be tracked?

Comment: After closing and re-opening the project and re-adding packages to index that were 'Untracked', all changed classes are now are tracked and on commit of the root package all classes that were modified are displayed.